# json.dumps encode multiple strings

Tags: python, json

I originally parse string as json format and upload to API. However, I face the encoding problem, so I try to use json.dmups to solve this problem.

**My original code:**

```
for i in range(len(data)):
    s = data[i]
    x = '{"msg" : "' + s + '"}'
    r = requests.post(url, data=x)
    data = r.json()
```

But if I want to use json.dumps to encode string s, I now if there is single string I can:

```
x = json.dumps({"msg" : "' + str + '"})
```

But how can I do so if my string = data[i]?
I've tried:

```
x = '{"msg" : "' + json.dumps(s) + '"}'
```

But it doesn't work:

```
Invalid \escape: line 1 column 76 (char 75)
```

Comment: You can try adding the `ensure_ascii=false` parameter to `json.dumps()` : you would have `x = '{"msg" : "' + json.dumps(s, ensure_ascii=false) + '"}'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an error with double quotes. JSON requires you to use double quotes, but python automatically converts them to single quotes.
The solution is this:

```
for piece in data:
    x = json.dumps({'msg': piece})
    r = requests.post(url, data=x)
    data = r.json()
```

Comment: In other words: don't cobble together JSON syntax yourself. Build a *Python dict/list*, and JSON-encode the entire thing at once.

Comment: Thank you so much!